# How do I determine if two d3 scales are equivalent OR if a d3 scale has changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using React with d3, and I'm trying to work out how to trigger renders correctly on scale changes. However, it's quite difficult to reliably detect if a scale has changed.

In theory, there's two routes I can think of to solve the issue.

I can generate the scales afresh on each render, and then have a reliable way of determining if two scales are the same (e.g. compare their domains, ranges, etc.). But there are still some problems—for example, I'm not actually sure how to distinguish a linear scale and a log scale with the same domains and ranges. (If I try a test value—say the midpoint of the domain—it will crash if given a non-numeric scale. I could avoid this by, uh, 'reverse-duck-typing' all of d3's various scales, but this seems extremely tedious, and potentially a performance sink if the test function becomes too compendious.)

The other solution would be to keep a consistent scale object across renders, but somehow get the scale to trigger a render if any of its properties have changed. I think this will end up amounting to the same thing as in the first option, but perhaps there's some trick in d3 that I don't know about that makes it easier?

Comment: I think the best answer to your question depends on whether you're using d3 in your render methods, or whether you're using d3 selectors inside other lifecycle methods.

Comment: How about using some utility variable to determine scale type at point where you are defining it, for example `var isLinear =true;` and modify it whenever you are changing your scale..

Answer (score 1):

(Warning: this is an **extremely** hacky solution to know what kind of scale you have. If you're not comfortable with it, please let me know and I'll delete it)

Every scale in D3 v4.x has a `copy` function, which exposes the type of the scale. For instance, this is the `copy` function of a linear scale:

```
scale.copy = function() {
    return copy(scale, linear());
};
```

This is the `copy` function of a band scale:

```
scale.copy = function() {
    return band()
        .domain(domain())
        .range(range)
        .round(round)
        .paddingInner(paddingInner)
        .paddingOuter(paddingOuter)
        .align(align);
};
```

And so on...

As you can see, the **type** of the scale is always present in the returned value (if you're using the non-minified version of D3).

Thus, we can use this to compare the scales (on top of comparing the domain and ranges, as you're doing right now). Here is an example:

```js
var scale1 = d3.scaleBand();
  
var scale2 = d3.scaleLinear();
  
var scale3 = d3.scaleLinear();
  
console.log("Is scale1 the same of scale2? " + (scale1.copy.toString() === scale2.copy.toString()))
console.log("Is scale1 the same of scale3? " + (scale1.copy.toString() === scale3.copy.toString()))
console.log("Is scale2 the same of scale3? " + (scale2.copy.toString() === scale3.copy.toString()))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And this can be used to test different scales that have the same domain and range (as you asked in your question):

```js
var scale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([10, 20])
  .range([10, 20]);

var scale2 = d3.scaleLog()
  .domain([10, 20])
  .range([10, 20]);

console.log("Is scale1 the same of scale2? " + (scale1.copy.toString() === scale2.copy.toString()))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Instead of comparing the `copy`, it's a better idea comparing the whole function. As @altocumulus pointed out in the [comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778840/how-do-i-determine-if-two-d3-scales-are-equivalent-or-if-a-d3-scale-has-changed/43779432#comment74603810_43779432), some scales return the same `copy`.

Comment: This breaks if you are using the minified version, though. For me, this feel a little too *hacky*.

Comment: @altocumulus No, it doesn't break, it works the same way with the minified version, since the *functions* are different, as you can see in the snippets. I know it's way too hacky, **extremely** means exactly that: reaching the highest degree.

Comment: My bad, I read just the first section and thought you were looking for the name literally. I followed a similar path which did not involve comparing `.copy()` but compared the whole function instead, i.e. `scale1.toString() === scale2.toString()`. But that is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes, you can use `scale.toString()` or `scale.copy.toString()`. Full disclosure: I used `copy` because I was trying to extract the scale name inside the `return`... then, bored and tired, I decided to use a simple `toString()` to write this answer.

Comment: After digging further into this my findings are, that you really should compare the entire functions, because `scalePow` and `scaleSqrt` as well as `scaleTime` and `scaleUtc` share the same copy method.

Comment: @altocumulus You're right, I tested some of them but not them all, and these two pairs are the same, indeed.